# http.FileServer caching files and serving old versions after edit

Tags: http, go

Having issues with the http package in the core of go. It appears that the file contents is cached although the Content-Length in the response body is correct. To demonstrate here is a simplified version of the application I am writing.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./www/")))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Now suppose we have a very simple html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Hello there</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I execute the go program and access `http://localhost:8080` in the browser to be presented with:

```
Hello there
```

Checking the response headers I can see the following:

```
Status Code:200 OK
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:68
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 20 Dec 2013 10:04:03 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 20 Dec 2013 10:03:32 GMT
```

Now I edit the html file so the `<p>` tag contains `Hello there everyone` and reload the page. I get the following:

```
Hello there
```

Again looking at the response headers I get

```
Status Code:200 OK
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:77
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 20 Dec 2013 10:04:34 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 20 Dec 2013 10:04:14 GMT
```

So the `Content-Length` has changed as well as last modified but not the actual file content delivered by the http.FileServer handler. This issue happens even after closing the program down and doing `go run src/.../main.go`. The only way I have found so far to clear the apparently cached version of the file is to reboot the machine the program is running on.

I have tried the following:

- Executing program on win / ubuntu / osx 10.8.5
- Going through the chain of functions / interfaces on golang.org/src to see if the served file is cached on disk anywhere

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a web browser or a command line tool?

Comment: Thanks for the input, please read the comments. I've replicated the behaviour with several web browsers, command line tools and by running the go server on windows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem using this version `go version go1.2 darwin/amd64`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, so after a few weeks of ignoring the problem and moving on I have finally worked out what the issue is.

In order to leave my main computer fairly uncustomised I use Vagrant to develop applications using golang, nodejs and php. It appears that running a go application on a Virtual Box share with all the html files stored on that share causes this issue.

To prove this I span up a Vagrant box and copied the files from the /vagrant shared directory to /home/vagrant/testing/, then replicated all the previously listed actions. This made the problem disappear.

So in other words, don't use a Virtual Box shared folder to host files intended for use in a http.FileServer method.

Comment: This is a problem with VirtualBox and using sendfile() (which net/http internally uses), see https://abitwiser.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/virtualbox-hates-sendfile/

Comment: I am now encountering this issue using a docker volume as well.

Answer (score 2):

Until VirtualBox has fixed the issue I made a go file that can be dropped into a project to disable sendfile support for the current process, go http package will then fallback to `io.Copy`. Also works with boot2docker with some small docker config changes.

https://github.com/wader/disable_sendfile_vbox_linux

With newer versions of [firejail](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail) you can do the same thing using:

```
firejail --seccomp.enotsup=sendfile ./program
```

Comment: Awesome, fixed the exact issue! I've known the issue is in vboxsf for a long time, which practically makes development on Win host + Linux guest unusable. It is unbelievable how long the bug has existed and not fixed.

Comment: Nice. If it is possible for you to develop using docker mac/windows i don't think you will need to hack anymore

Answer (score 1):

If you use some kind of an proxy, that would be the problem. Some proxies cache frequently used files (usually only .js, .css etc., but usually not .html) and ip addresses. If the server is on your local computer, try to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead of an ip address, so the request doesn't go trough the proxy. If it's not you have to configure or disable the proxy to access the newest version of the website. I don't know how common this is but, it would be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input. There is no proxy in place the server is running on the local machine (of which I have tried a mac, a windows pc and an ubuntu pc). The issue is replicated cross-browser, on the command line (wget, etc.) and with the go program running on several different machines (windows, mac, linux) in VMs and on physical machines.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a client issue, what browser are you using ?
Maybe you could try different browsers, curl, wget etc...

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've tried chrome and ff on Ubuntu/os10.8.5/win and ie10/11. Not tried with curl/wget but not much point if it fails with all those browser/os combinations.

Comment: Browser can cache responses among restarts and system reboots but wget wont.

Comment: Hi, yeup I understand that. I have now tested with wget and as before the same issue exists. I was pretty sure it would not be a browser issue as tried several browsers, completely clearing cache between editing the html file being served.