# Go Server Constantly Serving Outdated Files

Tags: html, css, caching, go

I'm using Go to build a website. When serving in static files, css and js, no matter what I do the updates to files will not show. I've tried cache busting, deleting cache in my web browser, and deleting the disk cache on my computer, but no matter what ( even across different browsers ) an old version of the file is served. I've looked all over an found no answers.

To illustrate, I have a file main.css

```
html {
    text-align:center;
}
```

However, the following css ( from an older file ) shows up in browser

```
html {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Chrome's Developer Tools saying the css is loading in with a status of 200.

**My Questions:**

1) What is going on?

2) How do I fix this issue?

My code is as follows:
**test.go**
    package main

```
import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type PageVariables struct {
    Name         string
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
    http.HandleFunc("/", HomePage)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}

func HomePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    HomePageVars := PageVariables{ //store the date and time in a struct
      Name: "PDiddy",
    }
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("homepage.html") //parse the html file homepage.html
    if err != nil { // if there is an error
      log.Print("template parsing error: ", err) // log it
    }
    err = t.Execute(w, HomePageVars) //execute the template and pass it the HomePageVars struct to fill in the gaps
    if err != nil { // if there is an error
      log.Print("template executing error: ", err) //log it
    }
}
```

**homepage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Welcome to HQ {{.Name}}</h1>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h2>Here's Whats Happening</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
          <h2>Select A Company</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running your server on your local machine or elsewhere? Can you show the browser requests? it should be obvious from that if it's requesting `main.css` or not.

Comment: I am running in on my vagrant box, using ubuntu 16.04. I'll try to post an image of what the network tab says in developer tools inside Chrome. It says it's requesting it, but an old version of it is always loaded in.

Comment: Ah, take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702221/http-fileserver-caching-files-and-serving-old-versions-after-edit, same issue, also on vagrant.

Comment: That was exactly it. You know, sometime I really, REALLY hate development. This is the stuff that makes you scream at your computer for hours. In short, you're a god send.

Comment: I'm out of flags for today, can someone mark this as dup and point to the question mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm create package with full copy of you code. All work well (add screenshot).
[image]

May be you need check package structure? My `tree` response.

```
.
├── homepage.html
├── static
│   └── css
│       └── main.css
└── test.go

2 directories, 3 files
```

Also I write unit-tests for you case. Please replace this lines to func init() in you test.go (for set handlers in `http.DefaultServeMux`)

```
 func init() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
    http.HandleFunc("/", HomePage)
 }
```

`test_test.go` this code compare equality static/css/main.css and http://localhost:8000/static/css/main.css.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func test(no int, name, addr, filepath string) error {
    var (
        err        error
        body, data []byte
        resp       *http.Response

        fmtError = func(step string, err error) error {
            return fmt.Errorf("Test #%d: error in testing <%s> in '%s' method
    %s", no, step, name, err)
        }
    )

    if resp, err = http.Get(addr); err != nil {
        return fmtError(fmt.Sprintf("HTTP GET %s", addr), err)
    } else if no == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    if data, err = ioutil.ReadFile(filepath); err != nil {
        return fmtError("read file", err)
    }

    if body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body); err != nil {
        return fmtError("read response data", err)
    } else if string(body) != string(data) {
        return fmtError("compare data", fmt.Errorf("File data and response body not equal"))
    } else if err = resp.Body.Close(); err != nil {
        return fmtError("HTTP response body close", err)
    }

    return nil
}

func TestServer(t *testing.T) {
    var (
        ts = httptest.NewServer(http.DefaultServeMux)

        testData = []struct {
            Name, Addr, File string
        }{
            {
                Name: "Index",
                Addr: "/",
                File: "homepage.html",
            },
            {
                Name: "main.css",
                Addr: "/static/css/main.css",
                File: "static/css/main.css",
            },
        }
    )
    defer ts.Close()

    for i, tt := range testData {
        if err := test(i, tt.Name, ts.URL+tt.Addr, tt.File); err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was not this my friend, it was an issue with deploying a go server inside a vagrant machine.